# When comparing two dates, do they need to be in the same format?

Tags: android, android-date

In Android, when I try to compare two dates using the following method

```
date1.before(date2)
```

Do I need to make sure date1 and date2 are in the same date format, such as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, or it does not matter?

Comment: it should not. But what class are you talking about.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi the  java.util.Date class

Comment: @rookiedev If you have any doubts then get their value in Long and compare them.

Comment: So your answer is no you do not have to change the format. The format is just that a format.

Comment: This might help http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.parse%28java.lang.String%29. You need to know that whatever format you use to create your date, some attributes will be calculated. It is does attributes that are used by the before method.

Comment: once you have parsed your date from String to Date/Calendar object, you don't have to care about format of dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any doubts then get their value in Long and compare them.

```
    Date d1 = new Date();
    Date d2 = new Date();
    Long.compare(d1.getTime(), d2.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare by SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String str1 = "12/10/2013";
Date date1 = formatter.parse(str1);

String str2 = "13/10/2013";
Date date2 = formatter.parse(str2);

if (date1.compareTo(date2)<0){
      System.out.println("date2 is Greater than my date1");                         
}

//or by timestamp
if(date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()){
      System.out.println("date2 is Greater than my date1");  
}
//or use after
if(date2.after(date1)){

}
```